# Want regex for glob api to find files

Tags: php, regex, pcre

My directory structure is like `D:/dir1/dir2/project_dir/dir3/dir4/dir5/cache/all_files`

So i want to get all the files under cache folder.
So i wrote

```
glob("project_dir/*/*/*/cache/*");
```

But cache folder is also there in dir3 or dir4 like

```
D:/dir1/dir2/project_dir/dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6/dir7/cache/all_files
```

or

```
D:/dir1/dir2/project_dir/dir3/cache/all_files
```

So can anyone give me the regex to get the files from 'cache' folder, 
like

```
glob("project_dir/*/cache/*");
```

Btw, this is not working because it is searching for immediate directory after `project_dir`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure `glob` accepts a regex? Try replacing `*` with `[^\/]+`.

Comment: I doubt `glob` can do this. Just write a snippet that recursively explores directories

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps!

Supports PHP 5 and 7 only,check your version before using this code

for more info refer : http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php

```
    $searchCacheFolderUnder = 'D:\xampp\htdocs\mygit\\'; 
    $pathOfAllCacheFolders = array();
    $dir = new DirectoryIterator(realpath($searchCacheFolderUnder));
    foreach ($dir as $fileInfo) {
        if($fileInfo->isDir()) {
            // optimize strpos with inbuild directory iterator methods
            if( strpos($fileInfo->getPathname(), 'cache') !== false ){
                $pathOfAllCacheFolders[] = $fileInfo->getPathname();
            }

        }
    }

    // contains all cache folders path
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($pathOfAllCacheFolders);
    echo "</pre>";

    // loop on all cache folders
    foreach($pathOfAllCacheFolders as $cachePath)
    $dirCache = new DirectoryIterator(realpath($cachePath));
    foreach ($dirCache as $fileInfo) {
        //$fileInfo object will have everything you need
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($fileInfo);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
```

You have to modify this code a bit to meet your requirement. Refer Directory Iterator for more available options.

Comment: You can optimize code for fast and better functioning

Comment: Thanks Mangesh...! this can be my solution, i'll find out more if get any pattern or not.. if not then i will use this one. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `glob('*')` but the only perk for using this is it ignores all hidden files. If you want all the files that includes hidden files in a folder then use:

```
$files = glob('project_dir/cache/{,.}*', GLOB_BRACE);
```

Remember this will return all the files for ".*" and "*" and even the directory entries . and .. Let me know in case of any issues.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Kishen,

How this will work, by this it is matching cache folder inside project_dir, but in my dir structure, in between there more directories.